# Does SQL Server add a byte order mark when casting to XML?

Tags: c#, sql-server, byte-order-mark

I have this C# method that is meant to ignore the byte order mark when serializing to XML:

```
public static string SerializeAsXml(this object dataToSerialize)
{
   if (dataToSerialize == null) return null;

   using (var stringwriter = new StringWriter())
   {
      var serializer = new XmlSerializer(dataToSerialize.GetType());

      serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, dataToSerialize);

      var xml = stringwriter.ToString();

      var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false);

      var bytes = utf8.GetBytes(xml);

      xml = utf8.GetString(bytes);

      return xml;
   }
}
```

The result is being passed to a stored procedure and cast to XML like this: `@EventMessage AS XML`

This stored procedure adds this as a message on a service broker queue.

But, when testing, the BOM is still present when retrieved from the queue.

Does SQL Server add a BOM itself when casting? And it so, is there a way to prevent this?

EDIT:

I retrieve the value from the queue with this query in a fitnesse test:

```
var sqlSelectCommand =
            $@"SELECT message_type_name, message_body, casted_message_body = 
            CASE message_type_name WHEN 'X' 
              THEN CAST(message_body AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
              ELSE message_body 
            END 
            FROM {QueueName} WITH (NOLOCK)";
```

This is read with this:

```
var castedMessageBody = reader["casted_message_body"].ToString();
```

And I know the BOM is still present because the test needs this to pass:

```
   if (castedMessageBody.StartsWith(_byteOrderMarkUtf8, StringComparison.Ordinal))
   {
       castedMessageBody = castedMessageBody.Remove(0, _byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length);
   }
```

Comment: *when testing, the BOM is still present when retrieved from the queue* How exactly? How do you store the value? How do you retrieve it?

Comment: I'll update the question

Comment: Isn't the cast just the problem?

Comment: XML is XML, a *specifc* type, not text. Why are you asking in the first place? BTW `WITH (NOLOCK)` means "read dirty data, ghosts and duplicates while taking excessive locks". It won't fix performance problems. It will *create* more problems

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? `StreamWriter` uses UTF8 by default. Even if it didn't, you'd just pass the desired encoding to its constructor. There's absolutely no need to manually convert to UTF8

Comment: The UTF8Encoding constructor takes a bool paramater to ignore the BOM, I was trying to avoid the problem that way

Comment: @Kieran you are *creating the problem in the first place*. Strings in .NET are *Unicode*, period. Everything after `stringwriter.ToString();` is pointless. Just return the string as is. It's the rest of the code that added the BOM

Comment: I didn't have that to start with, i just had up to stringwriter but the bom was still there

Comment: the encoding bit was my attempt at a fix

Comment: @Kieran `StringWriter` writes to strings. It doesn't care about BOMs. XmlSerializer doesn't use BOMs either, they are the responsibility of StreamWriter. How do you know there's a BOM at all? How did you check the string? Do you have code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Kieran if your code *adds* a BOM before storing the string to the database, you'll get a BOM back when you read the text.

Comment: In the edit the if statement removes the byte order mark from the data retrieved from the queue. With this it passed before and after my attempted fix. Without it failed (before and after). Maybe the BOM is added elsewhere

Comment: @Kieran there's nothing to fix. I can't reproduce what you claim. `xml` is a plain-old Unicode string whose first character is `<`. Try `        xml.ToCharArray()[0]` to check the first character in the string. Do you *save* the object to a file perhaps?

Comment: No, I just call the method and pass as a param. I see what you're saying though, so I'll look through the stored procedures and queries to see what I find. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically I don't think it does add a BOM when casting as XML [since](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-type-and-columns-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#xml-storage-options):

> The data is stored in an internal representation that preserves the XML content of the data. This internal representation includes information about the containment hierarchy, document order, and element and attribute values. Specifically, the InfoSet content of the XML data is preserved

Since the BOM is an artefact of *string encodings* of XML and not part of the XML Infoset, I don't think a BOM is stored.

*However*, if you cast the XML data into a binary or string representation in SQL Server, it appears to prefer a UTF-16 encoding with BOM as the representation you receive.